# Python - Sending Arabic E-Mails using smtplib

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I'm trying to send and email including Arabic and Persian characters, using smtplib. The Following is my Function:

```
def send_email (admin, pwd, user, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(admin, pwd)
    server.sendmail(admin, user, message)
    server.close()
    return True

send_email('sender@example.com', 'example', 'reciever@example.com', 'کاراکتر فارسی و عربی Persian and Arabic Characters')
```

and, I get the following error:

```
msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try .encode('UTF-8') 
hope it'll help

Answer (score 1):

The following code should solve your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import smtplib
import email.mime.text

    def send_email (admin, pwd, user, message):
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(admin, pwd)
        server.sendmail(admin, user, message)
        server.close()
        return True

    msg = email.mime.text.MIMEText("پایتون", _charset="UTF-8")
    print send_email('send@gmail.com', 'passwd', 'rec@gmail.com', msg.as_string())`
```